# How to add multiple tables dynamically in scroller in qt

Tags: qt, qt4

I am adding three tables dynamically in widget containing table widget and labels, but nothing shows on screen, I have tried to do it with vertical layout but it does not expand if i add a new row, so not scrolling.
Is there any other way to get all three tables on a same page with scrolling.

```
QScrollArea *m_scrollArea =ui->scrollArea_Stats;
m_scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(true);
QWidget *area = new QWidget;
QVBoxLayout *vlay = new QVBoxLayout(m_scrollArea);
area->setLayout(vlay);
StatsWidget *objStatsWidget;

for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
{
    objStatsWidget=new StatsWidget(ui->scrollArea_Stats);
    vlay->addWidget(objStatsWidget);
}

 m_scrollArea->setWidget(area);
```

here StatsWidget is my custom widget containing 2 lables at top and a table widget
I am adding three tables dynamically but page is not scrolling, vlay is not showing all tables it is just showing what it can show in a page without scrolling.

Comment: Please add the code where you add the tables to the widget as there are several ways to do that and we can't tell which one you are using.

Comment: Is it necessary to take a VBoxLayout for displaying the widget?

Comment: I think the actual problem is that your widget does not resize to the size which is required so that you can see all three tables (plus the already existing stuff) at once, right?

Comment: no you can move your object by hand but it is very improper..

Comment: @TimMeyer yes widget is not resizing according to the size of tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try rewrite the code as this:

```
m_scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(true);
QVBoxLayout *vlay = new QVBoxLayout;
StatsWidget *objStatsWidget;

for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
{
    objStatsWidget=new StatsWidget(ui->scrollArea_Stats);
    vlay->addWidget(objStatsWidget);
}
 QWidget *area = new QWidget(m_scrollArea);
 area->setLayout(vlay);
 m_scrollArea->setWidget(area);
```

EDIT: i made something like what you are trying to do some time ago.. 
so: create a custom `QWidget` with a `QVBoxLayout` as member.let's call this object "widgetList". then reimplement all method that you need, as `addWidget`, `takeAt`  etc.. using your layout as a list
finally set widgetList as widget for your scroll area.. 
let me know..

I made all this because `QWidgetList` was not enough easy to use and i needed something else that i have omitted here..

I found my piece of code:

```
class WidgetList : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    WidgetList(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~WidgetList();

    void addWidget(QWidget*);
    void removeWidget(QWidget*);

    QList<QWidget*> getListWidget() const;
    QWidget* takeAt(int) const;
    int count() const;

private:
    QVBoxLayout* layout_;
};
```

.cpp

```
WidgetList::WidgetList(QWidget *parent)
    : /**/QWidget(parent)
      /**/,layout_(new QVBoxLayout(this))
{
    this->setLayout(layout_);
}


void WidgetList::removeWidget(QWidget* widget)
{
    layout_->removeWidget(widget);
}

void WidgetList::addWidget(QWidget* widget)
{
    layout_->addWidget(widget);
}

QWidget* WidgetList::takeAt(int index) const
{
    return layout_->takeAt(index)->widget();
}

int WidgetList::count() const
{
    return layout_->count();
}
```

this will be your new Widget with layout where to insert your custom widget..
then i put `widgetList` as widget of `QScrollArea`:

```
QScrollArea* scrollArea = new QScrollArea;
widgetList* list = new widgetList(scrollArea);
scrollArea->setWidget(list);
```

everything works for me..

EDIT 2: i post my main that works good with my previous code:

```
QScrollArea* scroll = new QScrollArea;
WidgetList* w = new WidgetList(scroll);
QLabel * label = new QLabel("Label1");
QLabel* label2 = new QLabel("label2");
QTableWidget* table = new QTableWidget(10,10);

w->addWidget(label);
w->addWidget(label2);
w->addWidget(table);

scroll->setWidget(w);
scroll->setWidgetResizable(true);
scroll->show();
```

Comment: I am not getting it.. I have already created a custom widget with a table widget in it, can you please add some snippets, it would be a great help.

Comment: if you can post more  code i can help you.. what objects are you putting inside scrollArea? i want to make a test with my code..

Comment: I am putting custom widget in scrollarea which consists of two labels at top and table widget below them,

Comment: there something wrong with your code because my code and some  `QWidget`s in it works good! where do you call `scrollArea.show()` ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8450/discussion-between-abhishek-and-riskio)